How do I pass parameters to the swc-plugin
I want to pass parameters to a custom swc-plugin to dynamically replace the value of a variable. How do I do this?
const swc = require("@swc/core");
const fs = require("fs");

const srcCode = `const a = 1;`;

swc.transform(srcCode, {
    "jsc": {
      "parser": {
        "syntax": "ecmascript"
      },
      "target": "es2015",
      "experimental": {
        "plugins": [
            ["/Users/chenwenliang/formal_project/baidu/personal-code/swc-plugin/target/wasm32-wasi/release/const_replace.wasm",{}],
        ]
      }
    },
    "minify": false
  }
  )
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.code);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });

I want to pass parameters to a custom swc-plugin to dynamically replace the value of a variable.
